# openlayer : How to add static image or constant image inside minimap

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to add mini-map or overview map with static image inside mini-map. Currently in all overview map examples, when we zoom in/out the main map overviewmap(minimap) also zooms in/out. How can I make as static image inside overview map.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: You can stop the overview map panning and zooming by specifying a view with a single resolution and constrained center https://codesandbox.io/s/overviewmap-forked-uxg20

Comment: Thanks Mike.Seems to be  resolution property makes difference here..